# Fetching an object from a service which hasn't yet been created

Tags: angularjs

Folks:

I have 2 controllers, ctrlA and ctrlB - both unrelated to each other but are within the same page.

`ctrlA` queries an end point and returns a json object `tags`, which is then passed to a service method `MyService.saveTags(tags)` to store the object.

`ctrlB` then needs to populate a $scope variable `$scope.tags` by fetching the `tags` object created via `ctrlA`.

The service:

```
.factory('MyService', function($http, $q, $window) {
  var myserviceFactory = {};
  var savedTags = {};

// ..other methods..

  myserviceFactory.saveTags = function(tags) {
    if(!savedTags.tags){
      console.log('saving tags..');
      savedTags.tags = tags;
    }
  };

  myserviceFactory.getSavedTags = function() {
    console.log('returning tags..');
    return savedTags.tags;
  };

  return myserviceFactory;
})
```

This issue appears to be `ctrlB` gets called first, so when `$scope.savedTags = MyService.getSavedTags();` runs, it returns undefined.

Question: Angular n00b here - what would be the best way to fetch the tags after `ctrlA` has populated the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a watch on the `getSavedTags` service method inside your `ctrlB` to know when is it populated. Something like

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return MyService.getSavedTags() },function(newValue) {
   if(newValue) {
      $scope.savedTags = newValue;
   }
});
```